# setcap cap_sys_time not working for wine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wine

I have been tasked with running our Windows only software on a Linux distro. So I've decided to run it on wine on Ubuntu 18.04. The Ubuntu is from a net-install, so I pretty much have nothing but X11, openbox, and I configure everything through xterm.

On Windows, our software receives the time from our equipment (running on IRIG-B from GPS satallite) and changes the system time, so that the computer time and the equipment time are in sync. The software verifies and attempts this every 5 minutes.

I left the software running on wine over the weekend with `wine "path"` without detaching the process from xterm and when I came back I noticed that I had gotten a bunch of these messages in xterm, every 5 minutes or so:

```
err:ntdll:NtSetSystemTime Cannot set time to Mon Jun 18 09:49:19 2018
, time adjustment -3153: Operation not permitted
```

So I check the wine source of `NtSetSystemTime` and see that it's a wrapper for `settimeofday`. So I look man page of `settimeofday` and it says that it requires `CAP_SYS_TIME`. So I `setcap` with `cap_sys_time+ep` for `wine-stable`, `wineserver`, and the software executable, but it doesn't work.

I have tried a combination of `+ep`, `+ei`, and `+eip`, but that doesn't work either. I've turned off the NTP using `timedatectl set-ntp 0` and have tried setting `set-local-rtc` on and off.

I have also tried changing the system time to about 10 minutes off to see if it would change it, but that didn't uncover anything either.

I have run out of things to try. What am I missing? I just need to be able to get the software to change the system time.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. After digging around for more wine related stuff, I realized there's actually a bunch more wine related stuff in `/usr/lib/wine`.

Even though `which wine` returns `/usr/bin/wine` which symlinks to `/usr/bin/wine-stable`, the one you really want to `setcap` is `/usr/lib/wine/wine`.

So all in all, this worked for me:

```
sudo setcap cap_sys_time+ep /usr/lib/wine/wine
```

I tested them all, and figured out which ones didn't need cap given to, and have concluded that only that one really needs cap.